# Fill blank cells based on another column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm importing a text file that follows the pattern on the first picture. I want to fill the blank cells according the respective color shown in picture two.

Is this possible using the Power Query editor in PowerBI?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Fill down should work if you replace "" with null. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/fill-values-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the column and fill down.  If needed, replace blank with null first